# Artifacts (line) with masks in SVG

Tags: svg, mask, artifacts

Artifacts (two fine lines in the corner) appear in a SVG that uses a mask.
I tried several browsers and zoom / resolutions, but those artifacts don't go away.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="mask" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
            <rect width="400" height="400" fill="white" />
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="30" fill="black" />
        </symbol>

        <mask id="mask-resized">
            <use xlink:href="#mask" width="394" height="394" x="3" y="3" />
        </mask>
    </defs>
        
    <rect width="400" height="400" fill="red" mask="url(#mask-resized)" />      
</svg>
```

The mask applied on the red-filled rectangle is using a resized mask by itself.
This setup is used for more complicated compositions, but for isolating this issue, this is a minimal reproducible test case.

[image: the artifact, two fine lines, in the upper left corner]
It appears as that the edges of the mask boundaries or the rectangle used inside the mask somehow appear in the final, masked image.

Comment: stroke-width="0" on your red rect gets rid of the problem

Comment: @MichaelMullany: Hmm, I applied `stroke-width="0"` on the red `<rect`, but the artifact lines are still there. Have I missed something? When I also apply it on the `<rect` inside the mask the artifacts are still there.

Comment: All combination of stroke-width="0" on either the masking and/or masked red rect solves the artifact on Win10/Chrome latest on my PC (Nvidia GPU)

Comment: @MichaelMullany: Thanks! Then this seems to be a rendering issue. The lines don't disappear in my case. Could you create a SVG that I can view directly that doesn't show line artifacts on your system? If there are still artifacts for me, then this is a unpredictable rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

Applying your x/y offsets and scaling directly to the `<mask>` should solve the problem:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc
}

svg {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="mask" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
            <rect width="400" height="400" fill="white" />
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="30" fill="black" />
        </symbol>

        <mask id="mask-resized">
            <use xlink:href="#mask" width="394" height="394" x="3" y="3" />
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect width="400" height="400" fill="red" mask="url(#mask-resized)" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="mask2" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
            <rect width="394" height="394" x="3" y="3" fill="white" />
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="30" fill="black" />
        </symbol>
        <mask id="mask-resized2" >
            <use xlink:href="#mask2" />
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect width="400" height="400" fill="red" mask="url(#mask-resized2)" />
</svg>
```